# Best practice child and parent script

Tags: unity, design-patterns

What is the best practice coming to where to place the code in this scenario.

I have a gamobject called **player**. It has lots of child objects. One of them is **sword**. 
Like this:

**Player**

- **Body**
- - **Head**
- - **Torso**
- - **Sword**

So i have code that controls the player in **player**. It controls movement and triggers an attack animation which swings the **sword**. The code that checks if the sword is swinging and if it has hit something is at the moment inside the sword. My question is, what model is best practice? I can think of some:

1. All code in **player**. **player** checks if **sword** is colliding and handles what happens to the **enemy** that was hit.
2. **sword** checks for collision but **player** handles it by polling **sword** and takes care of what happens with **enemy** and **player** after.
3. **sword** checks for collision but **player** handles it  by listening to an event that **sword** triggers and takes care of what happens with **enemy** and **player** after.
4. **sword** handles everything by handling what happens to **enemy** and **player** communicating with parent through a reference.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based. Choose the option that makes the most sense to you and works best for your project.

Comment: I have no doubts it can work any how. I would just like to hear pros and cons or problems that different scenarios can give.

Comment: Yep, I know what you want to hear. If you tell us the specific problem you're having with the current implementation we could probably tell you which strategy to use to avoid that. Otherwise it's just kind of an open ended question.

Comment: Sorry. Im not really having troubles. Just trying to figure out what way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true, as said by Byte56 that's quite a matter of opinion. But the choiche you have proposed have different consequences:

> 1 - All code in player. player checks if sword is colliding and handles what happens to the enemy that was hit.

and

> 2 - sword checks for collision but player handles it by polling sword and takes care of what happens with enemy and player after.

1 and 2 are basically the same (am I wrong? otherwise correct me), because its the child object(sword) that will be notified of the collision. So if the child doesn't awake the player, then the player must perform some kind of polling.
Personally I hate polling for several reasons:

1. Polling code looks ugly
2. Performance: you are doing a lot of unuseful polling checks at every frame, in order to catch an event that is some way occasional (sword hit enemy)

Personal opinion: I'd stay away from polling whenever possible.

> 3 - sword checks for collision but player handles it by listening to an event that sword triggers and takes care of what happens with enemy
>   and player after.

I think that's the best.

1. Player's code will be more clean and efficient.
2. It's really simple to enable/disable the hit handling, simply removing the delegate associated with the event.
3. If you have more classes interested to listen to the hit event, it's easy to broadcast this event to all listeners (es. audio manager that plays an effect on sword hit)

Personally I'll go this way (or something similar).

> 4 - sword handles everything by handling what happens to enemy and
>   player communicating with parent through a reference.

This is better than polling for what concern player's code, but introduce a not necessary dependency of the player inside sword class. This means that if you want to reuse your sword component for other entities than player (es. enemies) you'll probably end up with branching in the sword code ( or eventually you need interface or some kind of abstraction to interact with player and enemies through the same methods).